# Find largest 15 log file from O drive in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find largest 15 log files greater than 1GB. Not sure if i am correct but my code giving me errors. See code example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.log -path o:\ -recurse | where { ($_.Length / 1GB) -gt 10 }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting specifically? Post the error message in full

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the 10 largest files in a directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798040/how-do-i-find-the-10-largest-files-in-a-directory-structure)

Answer (score 1):

Without the errors, hard to say, but I think you should probably add the -File parameter.  Might look something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.log -Path o:\ -Recurse -File | 
Where-Object{ ($_.Length / 1GB) -gt 10 } | 
Sort-Object Length |
Select-Object -Last 15
```

I'd also be on the lookout for access errors, but we can only deal with it if we know what they are and if they are important to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Getting errors

 Get-ChildItem -Filter *.log -Path o:\ -Recurse -File |
>> Where-Object{ ($_.Length / 1GB) -gt 10 } |
>> Sort-Object Length |
>> Select-Object -Last 15
Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'O:\OracleAgent\agent_13.3.0.0.0\install\oneoffs\agent\25237184\files
\oracle.wsm.agent.thirdparty\12.1.3.0.0\oracle.wsm.agent.thirdparty.symbol\modules\oracle.wsm.agent.thirdparty.common_1
2.1.3\wsm-asm-dependencies.jar\oracle\wsm\agent\tpa\common\annotation'.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: I'm guessing the path is too long.  These can echo funny sometimes, but that path is already 259 chars.

It depends if you really expect to find log files that deep.  If not, I'd Add -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to the Get-ChildItem command.